# ERROR on Recently Viewed: INVALID_TYPE: record type xxxxxx doesn't belong to xxObjectxxx

Tags: lightning-experience, recentlyviewed

Recently switched over to Lightning from Classic. Got this error in testing but never able to replicate it.

Assumed it was an issue during development but now a user is getting it in Production when clicking on the Lead tab which loads the Recently Viewed.

The record type shown isn't complete, it is missing the last 3 digits but the first digits correspond to an Account record type.

I can't recreate this error.  I tried logging in as the user that is getting the error message, but it doesn't error out for me.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess you might have been exposed to a know issue [Kanban view gets into irreparable bad state over record type confusion](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000JX7YQAW&title=kanban-view-gets-into-irreparable-bad-state-over-record-type-confusion). Also there is no workaround mentioned in the known issue. Your best best bet would be reaching out to support and raise a case.